# Convert single column variable into multiple columns

Tags: r

How do I convert a variable such as this into a dataframe with multiple columns?

```
1   18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1    chevrolet chevelle malibu
2   15.0   8   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70  1    buick skylark 320
3   18.0   8   318.0      150.0      3436.      11.0   70  1    plymouth satellite
4   16.0   8   304.0      150.0      3433.      12.0   70  1    amc rebel sst
5   17.0   8   302.0      140.0      3449.      10.5   70  1    ford torino
6   15.0   8   429.0      198.0      4341.      10.0   70  1    ford galaxie 500
```

The imported data makes it a single column instead of multiple columns. I tried separate but it separated the numbers at the decimal points.

```
auto.mpg %>% separate(V1,c("mpg","cylinders","displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year","origin"))
```

```
  mpg cylinders displacement power weight acceleration year origin                                   V2
1    18         0            8   307      0          130    0   3504            chevrolet chevelle malibu
2    15         0            8   350      0          165    0   3693                    buick skylark 320
3    18         0            8   318      0          150    0   3436                   plymouth satellite
4    16         0            8   304      0          150    0   3433                        amc rebel sst
5    17         0            8   302      0          140    0   3449                          ford torino
6    15         0            8   429      0          198    0   4341                     ford galaxie 500
```

Current data set:

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear from the post above what it is you're trying to do. Posting your data using `dput()`, an example of your desired output, and what you've been trying would be helpful. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to post a good, reproducible example so we can better answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```r
auto.mpg <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, (strsplit(as.character(auto.mpg$V1), " {2,10}"))))
auto.mpg
#   V1   V2 V3    V4    V5    V6   V7 V8 V9                       V10
# 1  1 18.0  8 307.0 130.0 3504. 12.0 70  1 chevrolet chevelle malibu
# 2  2 15.0  8 350.0 165.0 3693. 11.5 70  1         buick skylark 320
# 3  3 18.0  8 318.0 150.0 3436. 11.0 70  1        plymouth satellite
# 4  4 16.0  8 304.0 150.0 3433. 12.0 70  1             amc rebel sst
# 5  5 17.0  8 302.0 140.0 3449. 10.5 70  1               ford torino
# 6  6 15.0  8 429.0 198.0 4341. 10.0 70  1          ford galaxie 500
```

and then

```
auto.mpg <- auto.mpg[,-1]
names(auto.mpg) <- c("mpg", "cylinders", "displacement", "power", 
                     "weight", "acceleration", "year", "origin", "model")
auto.mpg
#    mpg cylinders displacement power weight acceleration year origin                     model
# 1 18.0         8        307.0 130.0  3504.         12.0   70      1 chevrolet chevelle malibu
# 2 15.0         8        350.0 165.0  3693.         11.5   70      1         buick skylark 320
# 3 18.0         8        318.0 150.0  3436.         11.0   70      1        plymouth satellite
# 4 16.0         8        304.0 150.0  3433.         12.0   70      1             amc rebel sst
# 5 17.0         8        302.0 140.0  3449.         10.5   70      1               ford torino
# 6 15.0         8        429.0 198.0  4341.         10.0   70      1          ford galaxie 500
```